# Networking |is Transmission Control Protocol(TCP) ensures fairness among multiple flows?

Tags: networking

is any variant of TCP is fair protocol. for example if there are morethan 1 TCP flows are participating in a network. Then does TCP ensures fairness?

Comment: All variants of TCP should be fair. The slow start and exponential backoff are sufficient to ensure that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP(All variations in use todays Internet) uses AIMD(Additive Increase Multiplicative Decrease) algorithm, which ensures fairness. How? Because hosts increase their bandwidth additively, but when congestion occurs they drop their bandwidth multiplicatively. So, the host with higher share, loses most. After that every host increase their share by same amount(additivitely). As this steps happens again and again, bandwidths converge to fair amounts.

A very good explanation video can be seen here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXmZivNiNTQ